# How to connect xml with a class on android

Tags: android

I have created a new .xml file named "new_game.xml" and a class named "New_Game.java"
***These are not Main activity***

new_game.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"               
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>               
              
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"                  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
        android:text="Click"                 
        android:id="@+id/button"              
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"                
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"/>              
                
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"                 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:inputType="textPersonName"                
        android:ems="10"                
        android:id="@+id/editText"               
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"               
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"             
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"/>         
       
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:id="@+id/imageView"       
        android:paddingTop="50dp"      
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"      
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"      
        android:paddingRight="50dp"      
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"       
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"       
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"/>      
</RelativeLayout>
```

New_Game.java:

```
package com.example.logosquiz;        

import android.app.Activity;        
import android.app.ListActivity;       
import android.app.TabActivity;         
import android.os.Bundle;        
import android.view.LayoutInflater;           
import android.view.View;      
import android.widget.Button;      
import android.widget.EditText;      
import android.widget.ImageView;      
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;    

public class New_Game extends Activity {     
     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        setContentView(R.layout.new_game);      
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);        
        final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);     

        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText1.setText("Hello Android");     
            }     
        });      
    }
```

Please explain it very well

I put on AndroidManifest.xml this

> ```
> <activity android:name=".New_Game"> /activity>
> ```

and this on the event onClick

> Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), New_Game.class);
>
> startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

Comment: on the .xml I have a button and an editText when I press the button I don;t show the message "Hello World" on editText. The problem is that I have not connected the class with the xml.

Comment: Do you get any errors, crash? I don't see anything wrong so far unless you are clicking the `ImageButton` first...that will give you problems. The xml is "connected" when you call `setContentView()`. Its called `inflating` the `layout` which makes it visible

Comment: no I don't get any error but the button don't do anything when I click it. The ImageButton is not important, I remove it now

Comment: I think the issue is your `layout` itself. Can you see all of the `Views` in the graphical view of your editor? Because there are some properties that don't look right to me

Comment: http://prntscr.com/18f2pv      this is what I see

Comment: try and clean your project and then run it

Comment: Goto Project -> Clean -> Select you project from the windoe -> OK, BTW this source worked perfectly for me if I remove the / from first RelativeLayout Tag. I wonder why eclipse din show you an error there

Comment: I am with Android studio but I don't think that they are different

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is wrong. Remove the last `/` from the first `RelativeLayout` in your XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"               
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

instead of

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"               
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Although Eclipse should have warned you about this.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but

button android:layout_marginTop="27dp"

edittext android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

edit text is placed on the button so when you click you are clicking on edittext not button change edittext marginTop to 30dp and check

```
public class New_Game extends Activity {
EditText editText1;
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

    setContentView(R.layout.new_game);      


     Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);        

    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);     

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);     

  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){     

        editText1.setText("Hello Android");     
}     
  });     

 }
```

Comment: i have edited my answer EditText should be declared at class level to be accessed in onclick if not it will ask you to make it final and if it is final value wont be changed. try the above code now it will work

Comment: nope not working even in this way. I think the problem is to put something else on " extends Activity" of the class

Comment: put @override before protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)